# I got 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' on this line of code in C#, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, arrays

I got 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' on this line of code in C#, what's wrong?

```
for (int j = 0; j < ja[i].Length; j++)
```

The complete code below:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] ja = new int[3][];
            ja[0] = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
            ja[1] = new int[2] { 4,1 };
            ja[2] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 1 };

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Element{0}", i++);
                for (int j = 0; j < ja[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(ja[i][j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to all this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is i++ in `Console.Write("Element{0}", i++)` above. because i is use again in `ja[i].Length`. it makes ja[3].Length in the last execution. because you only define ja count = 3, so it make the error that you mention above.

in the other hand the i++ is impacted to the i variable itself, it make the i value changed.

```
 int[][] ja = new int[3][];
    ja[0] = new int[2] { 1, 2 };
    ja[1] = new int[2] { 4, 1 };
    ja[2] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < ja.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Element{0}", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < ja[i].Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(ja[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. Can you tell why was that causing the problem?